# How can I use microsoft windows xp or 7 and ubuntu lts on same computer?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-xp

I want to use windows xp and ubuntu lts on same pc. How can I do it?
and
is ubuntu free os or we have to purchase it for proffesional or for best use?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please ask one question at a time. For the first question, search for how to install Ubuntu here and see the ubuntu.com web site. You don't have to purchase Ubuntu. It is opensource and free like Firefox etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Ubuntu is completely open source operating system and you not need to pay anything for any type of use.

Here is your solution to install Windows with Ubuntu.

[Windows Xp with Ubuntu Dual Boot](http://www.wikihow.com/Dual-Boot-Windows-XP-and-Ubuntu)